# SELECT SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand, selectcommand

I know this is a simple question, but I can't get it to work.

This is my query in my `SqlCommand`:

```
SELECT * FROM zipcode  WHERE city LIKE @prefixtext + '%' ;
```

I only want 10 results, every other answer suggests

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM zipcode  WHERE city LIKE @prefixtext + '%' ;
SELECT * FROM zipcode  WHERE city LIKE @prefixtext + '%'  LIMIT 10 ;
```

both do not work

Comment: I'm likely wrong on this since I'm not very familiar with SQL Server, but I don't think that + is concatenation.

Comment: Is `zipcode` really your table name, or the name of the column you want to retrieve? Basic query format is `SELECT column_name` (or `*` for all columns) ` FROM table_name WHERE ...`

Comment: @Corbin, `+` does concatenate string in SQL Server.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ah...  Was worth a shot :)

Comment: zipcode is the correct table name

Comment: so what does the the error say ?  Are you sure the computer has gas in it?  Is it plugged in ?  Maybe there's a bug...  Seriously,   you need to provide more inormation about what is wrong than just "both do not work" ...  Are you getting 11 records instead of 10 ? or are you getting records from the wrong server ? or from the wrong table?  no records at all?

Comment: TOP 10 is SQL Server specific.  LIMIT 10 works on MySQL (maybe also Oracle?).  Which DB are you using?  What error or incorrect result do you get?

Comment: MSSQL  "Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'."

Comment: SELECT TOP 10 * FROM zipcode WHERE city LIKE @prefixtext + '%' would definitely work in MSSQL, limit 10 is not MSSQL keyword. What is the error here?

Comment: ok, error with 'LIMIT 10'  - SELECT TOP 10 returning nothing , has to be bad query , thank you

Comment: try replacing star with actual column name you want to return. When you remove TOP 10 from query does it work?

Comment: Could you show the code where you populate the `SqlCommand` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe these are all correct.

Oracle:

```
select * from zipcode where city like @prefixtext + '%' and rownum <=10
```

SQL Server/Sybase:

```
select top 10 * from zipcode where city like @prefixtext + '%'
```

DB2/PostgreSQL:

```
select * from zipcode where city like @prefixtext || '%' fetch first 10 rows only
```

MySQL:

```
select * from zipcode where city like @prefixtext + '%' limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @like varchar(50)

set @like = @prefixtext + '%';

SELECT TOP 10 * FROM zipcode  WHERE city LIKE @like
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from zipcode where city like @prefixtext + '%'
```

Comment: Does not keep to " I only want 10 results"